# Go html/template automatic json encoding

Tags: templates, go

Although I guess it could be a bug in Go template, and filed an issue:

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/38895

I would like to ask here, the "by design" behavior of Go's html/template, especially it's rule with `<script>` tag.  See below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

type User struct {
    ID   int    `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {
    u := User{1, "xrfang"}
    //without <script>
    t, _ := template.New("body").Parse("var u = {{.}}")
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, u)
    fmt.Println()
    //with <script>
    t, _ = template.New("body").Parse("<script>/*var u1 = {{.}}*/ var u2 = {{.}}</script>")
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, u)
    fmt.Println()
}
```

The template without `<script>` generated string same as output of go's `%+v` fmt string.  But the `<script>` version generated JSON, **and** the code in-between `/* ... */` is automatically removed??

Answer (score 3):

> The template without  generated string same as output of go's %+v fmt string. But the  version generated JSON, and the code in-between /* ... */ is automatically removed??

Yes. That is intentional. Escaping in html/template is context specific as it must be context specific to be safe as explained in the package doc.

Comment: ok, this just confirms my finding, but the problem still exists, as I described in the bug report